# "export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i23') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm updating Angular version from 7 to 8. But when I build it even though I don't use DOCUMENT, it gives me an error. What could it be that I'm not seeing? I looked through all the files but couldn't find DOCUMENT used with '@angular/platform-browser'. I even checked for '@angular/common'.

I'm just using document here but it has nothing to do with '@angular/platform-browser'. Because it uses it from lib.dom.d.ts.

```
const element = document.querySelector('button.submit-button');
```

```
ERROR in ./src/app/survey/questionlist/questionlist.module.ngfactory.js 53:2332-2344
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i23') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/period/periodlist/periodlist.module.ngfactory.js 53:2326-2338
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i23') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/insurancetype/insurancetypelist/insurancetypelist.module.ngfactory.js 53:2347-2359
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i23') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/report/audit/audit.module.ngfactory.js 57:2366-2378
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i24') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/report/gift/gift.module.ngfactory.js 54:2363-2375
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i24') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/report/benefit/benefit.module.ngfactory.js 56:2372-2384
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i24') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/user/list/list.module.ngfactory.js 59:2395-2407
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i25') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/company/list/list.module.ngfactory.js 57:2395-2407
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i25') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/benefit/calculation/calculation.module.ngfactory.js 56:2416-2428
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i25') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/benefit/calculation/calculation-list/calculation-list.module.ngfactory.js 56:2428-2440
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i25') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/benefit/list/list.module.ngfactory.js 56:2395-2407
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i25') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/dashboard/list/list.module.ngfactory.js 74:2433-2445
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i26') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/giftcard/giftcardlist/giftcardlist.module.ngfactory.js 64:2543-2555
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i27') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./src/app/ruleSet/rulelist/rulelist.module.ngfactory.js 68:2563-2575
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i28') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/components/header/header.component.ngfactory.js 73:98-109
"export 'DOCUMENT' (imported as 'i8') was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/typescript": "^2.0.0-5d0e199",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^0.21.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.3.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "11.1.5",
    "X-editable": "github:vitalets/x-editable",
    "angular-dual-listbox": "^5.0.1",
    "angular-tabs-component": "^1.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-colorpicker": "2.5.2",
    "bootstrap-duallistbox": "3.0.6",
    "bootstrap-markdown": "2.10.0",
    "bootstrap-progressbar": "0.9.0",
    "bootstrap-slider": "10.0.0",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "0.5.2",
    "chart.js": "2.7.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "clockpicker": "0.0.7",
    "clone": "2.1.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "date-input-polyfill": "^2.14.0",
    "debounce": "1.1.0",
    "dropzone": "5.2.0",
    "dygraphs": "2.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "fuelux": "3.16.2",
    "he": "1.1.1",
    "highcharts": "6.0.3",
    "ion-rangeslider": "2.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-jcrop": "0.9.13",
    "jquery-knob": "1.2.11",
    "jquery-ui-npm": "1.12.0",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.19.3",
    "jquery.maskedinput": "1.4.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "markdown": "0.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "morris.js": "0.5.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "0.2.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
    "ngx-mask": "^8.0.6",
    "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
    "nouislider": "10.1.0",
    "raphael": "2.2.7",
    "rea-tinymce": "^1.0.14",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "scriptjs": "2.5.8",
    "select2": "4.0.6-rc.1",
    "smartadmin-plugins": "1.0.21",
    "tinymce": "^4.9.3",
    "to-markdown": "3.1.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.29",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.4.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.16",
    "@types/node": "8.0.54",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.4",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "5.2.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "script-loader": "0.7.2",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.8.0",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2"
  },
```

Comment: Can you try reinstalling dependencies? You can follow steps - 1.rm -rf node_modules 2.npm cache verify 3.npm install

Comment: I did it. But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed when I updated the @swimlane/ngx-datatable package from 11.1.5 to version 16.1.1. Because version 11.1.5 of @swimlane/ngx-datatable package was using old version of "@angular/platform-browser" package. And in the old version DOCUMENT couldn't find it because it was moved to "@angular/common'". If it gives you an error even though you do not use it in your codes, please check your package versions. For example DOCUMENT. You may not be using DOCUMENT but the @swimlane/ngx-datatable package does. And it needs the latest version or the version available.

```
npm uninstall @swimlane/ngx-datatable
npm i @swimlane/ngx-datatable@16.1.1
```

And replace

```
import { DatatableComponent } from "@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release";
```

with

```
import { DatatableComponent } from "@swimlane/ngx-datatable"
```